# Refreshing RecyclerView in Kotlin problem

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm successfully passing data from MainActivity to my recyclerView via adapter, and my view with items is rendering correctly. However, I need to change one member of my item object on click (status), and i wrote a method for that (updateStatus), and it works great, it changes the value and save it to database.

But i cannot refresh my recyclerView, so it could render changed Status attribute. I need to go back on my phone, reenter, and then it renders it correctly. I have tried everything, from notifyDataSetChanged to restarting adapter, no luck. There is something missing and I can't find what.

Here is my MainActivity class

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var posiljkaDAO: PosiljkaDAO? = null

    private var dostavnaKnjizicaDAO: DostavnaKnjizicaDAO? = null
    private var allItems: ArrayList<DostavnaKnjizicaModel> = arrayListOf()
    var adapter = RecycleViewAdapter(allItems)

    private var eSifraPosiljke: EditText? = null

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_listview)

        //get logo
        supportActionBar!!.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true)
        supportActionBar!!.setLogo(R.drawable.logo_bp)
        supportActionBar!!.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true)

        dostavnaKnjizicaDAO = DostavnaKnjizicaDAO(this)
        dostavnaKnjizicaDAO?.closeDB()

        getAllItems(this)
        //connecting adapter and recyclerView
        adapter = RecycleViewAdapter(allItems)
        recycleView.adapter = adapter
        recycleView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        recycleView.setHasFixedSize(true)

        eSifraPosiljke = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.eSifraPosiljke)

        posiljkaDAO = PosiljkaDAO(this)
   
    }
    //method that gets all items from database
    private fun getAllItems(context: Context) {
        var dostavenFromLOcal = dostavnaKnjizicaDAO?.getAllLocalDostavneKnjizice(context)
        if (dostavenFromLOcal != null) {
            allItems = dostavenFromLOcal
        }
    }
    //method that changes status of an item
    fun changeStatus(context: Context, IdDostavne: Int, statusDostavne: Int) {
        dostavnaKnjizicaDAO = DostavnaKnjizicaDAO(context)
        dostavnaKnjizicaDAO?.changeStatus(IdDostavne, statusDostavne)
        getAllItems(context)
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

    }
}
```

and my Adapter class

```
class RecycleViewAdapter(var dostavneKnjiziceBP: ArrayList<DostavnaKnjizicaModel>)
    : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecycleViewAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){
        val nazivPrimaoca: TextView = view.txtNazivPrimaoca
        val brojPosiljke: TextView = view.txtBrojPosiljke
        val statusDostave: TextView = view.txtStatusDostave
        val imgMore: ImageView = view.img_more
        val context: Context = view.context
    }
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {

        val layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.urucenje_posiljke_layout, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(layoutView)
    }
    override fun getItemCount() = dostavneKnjiziceBP.size


    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        //New variable to get all modeliPosiljakaBP and their position
        var dosKnjizica = dostavneKnjiziceBP[position]

        val mainActivity = MainActivity()
        //Sending data to layout for display in specific field
        if (dosKnjizica.naziv_primaoca != null) {
            holder.brojPosiljke.text = "${dosKnjizica.id_dostavna_knjizica}, "
            holder.nazivPrimaoca.text = "${dosKnjizica.naziv_primaoca}"
            if (dosKnjizica.naziv_primaoca!!.length > 25) {
                holder.nazivPrimaoca.text = "${dosKnjizica.naziv_primaoca!!.subSequence(0, 25)}..."
            }
        } else {
            holder.brojPosiljke.text = "${dosKnjizica.id_dostavna_knjizica}"
            holder.nazivPrimaoca.text = ""
        }
        holder.statusDostave.text = "${dosKnjizica.status_dostave_naziv}"

        when (dosKnjizica.status_dostave) {
            StatusDostaveEnum.Neurucena.value -> {
                holder.statusDostave.setTextColor(Color.RED)
            }
            StatusDostaveEnum.Uruceno.value, StatusDostaveEnum.ZaRejon.value, StatusDostaveEnum.Nadoslano.value, StatusDostaveEnum.Izgubljeno.value -> {
                holder.statusDostave.setTextColor(Color.GREEN)
            }
            StatusDostaveEnum.Obavjesteno.value, StatusDostaveEnum.ZaNarednuDostavu.value -> {
                holder.statusDostave.setTextColor(Color.BLUE)
            }
            StatusDostaveEnum.Retour.value -> {
                holder.statusDostave.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#dda0dd"))
            }
        }

        //Calling menu menu_pregled_drugih_vrsta_posiljke to display menu options on click on three dots
        holder.imgMore.setOnClickListener {
            val popupMenu = PopupMenu(holder.context, it, Gravity.START)
            popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener { item ->
                when (item.itemId) {
                    R.id.uruci -> {
                        //calling new activity from second item in dropdown menu
                        holder.imgMore.context.startActivity(
                            Intent(holder.imgMore.context, MainActivityInfo::class.java).putExtra(
                                "Id", dosKnjizica.id_dostavna_knjizica.toString()
                            )
                        )
                        true
                    }
                    //here i am calling my changeStatus method from MainActivity
                    R.id.obavjesti -> {
                        mainActivity.changeStatus(holder.context, dosKnjizica.id_dostavna_knjizica!!, StatusDostaveEnum.Uruceno.value)
                        Toast.makeText(holder.context, "obavjesti", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        true
                    }
                    R.id.vrati -> {
                        Toast.makeText(holder.context, "vrati", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        true
                    }
                    else -> false
                }
            }
            popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.menu_urucenje_posiljke)
            popupMenu.show()
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your adapter doesn't have the updated data. Initially, you fetch all data from the database and create an adapter with it: `adapter = RecycleViewAdapter(allItems)`. Afterwards, you are updating the database, calling `getAllItems(Context)` but you don't pass the data to the adapter.

Add the line `adapter.dostavneKnjiziceBP = allItems` to the `changeStatus` method like this:

```
//method that changes status of an item
fun changeStatus(context: Context, IdDostavne: Int, statusDostavne: Int) {
    dostavnaKnjizicaDAO = DostavnaKnjizicaDAO(context)
    dostavnaKnjizicaDAO?.changeStatus(IdDostavne, statusDostavne)
    getAllItems(context)
    adapter.dostavneKnjiziceBP = allItems
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Save `dostavneKnjiziceBP` as a private var inside the adapter and create functions for assigning and updating that `ArrayList` from within the adapter, using `notifyDataSetChanged()` everytime a change is done.

```
class RecycleViewAdapter internal constructor(
    context: Context
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecycleViewAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    private var items = ArrayList<DostavnaKnjizicaModel>()

    // ...

    internal fun setItems(items: ArrayList<DostavnaKnjizicaModel>) {
        this.items = items
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = this.items.size
}
```

Also, try using `adapter.notifyItemChanged(updateIndex);` if you know the index of the updated item.